# Copying large database is slow. How can I speed up the process?

Tags: mysql, javadb

I am copying a database from Java DB to MySQL. All the tables are set up correctly in MySql, and I wrote a method for copying the database.

There are no errors in the method, it works perfectly on tables that are limited in size. But it is too slow for large tables. It took about 5 min 29 sec to copy 7937 records! Since one table has 2.3 million records I would have to wait for more than 26 hours...

I ran it in Netbeans and my output is here: (batch size = 2000)

```
run:
------    Copying table currency ------ 
26 rows needs to be copied
Executed batch for currency, inserted the last 26 elements
------    Finished copying table currency ------ 

------    Copying table exchange ------ 
31 rows needs to be copied
Executed batch for exchange, inserted the last 31 elements
------    Finished copying table exchange ------ 

------    Copying table markets ------ 
82 rows needs to be copied
Executed batch for markets, inserted the last 82 elements
------    Finished copying table markets ------ 

------    Copying table trade ------ 
2303371 rows needs to be copied
Executed batch for trade, inserted 2000 elements     Have copied a total of 2000/2303371 rows, 0%
Executed batch for trade, inserted 2000 elements     Have copied a total of 4000/2303371 rows, 0%
Executed batch for trade, inserted 2000 elements     Have copied a total of 6000/2303371 rows, 0%
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 5 minutes 29 seconds)
```

So i stopped the execution when I saw that this would take much longer time than anticipated.

```
 
/**
     * 
     * @param javadb Connection to the source database
     * @param mysql Connection the target database
     * @param orderedTables table names in the order they are to be copied (so no foreign key constraints error stuff happens)
     */
    public static void copyFromJavaDBtoMySQL(Connection javadb, Connection mysql, String[] orderedTables, int batchSize){
        Statement javadb_stmnt = null;
        PreparedStatement mysql_stmnt = null;

        try {
           for (int i = 0; i < orderedTables.length; i++){
                //Print out some information on which table isbeing copied and how many rows that table contains.
                System.out.println("------    Copying table " + orderedTables[i] + " ------ ");
                int numberRows = DataBase.executeCountQuery(orderedTables[i], null); //A helper method for getting rows in table
                System.out.println(numberRows + " rows needs to be copied");

                int totalNumberCopied = 0;
```

`//Get resultset from source table
            String selectQuery = "select * from " + orderedTables[i];
            javadb_stmnt = javadb.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs_select = javadb_stmnt.executeQuery(selectQuery);

            //Creating insert query for target table. Query will be 'insert into <tablename> values (?, ?, ..., ?)'
            int colCount = rs_select.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            String insert_query = "insert into " + orderedTables[i] + "( ";
            String valuesSubstring = "values (";
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount-1; j++){
                insert_query += rs_select.getMetaData().getColumnName(j+1) + ", ";
                valuesSubstring += "?, ";
            }
            insert_query += rs_select.getMetaData().getColumnName(colCount) + ") ";
            insert_query += valuesSubstring + "?)";

            //Use prepared statement with batches
            mysql_stmnt = mysql.prepareStatement(insert_query);            
            int counter = 0;

            //Iterate over resultset from source table
            while (rs_select.next()){
                //Add batch to insert statement from the current row in result set
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++){
                    Object obj = rs_select.getObject(j);
                    mysql_stmnt.setObject(j, obj);
                }
                mysql_stmnt.addBatch();   
                //If I have added enough inserts, execute the batch insert
                if (++counter == batchSize){
                    int[] arr = mysql_stmnt.executeBatch();
                    //Print out some progressinformation
                    totalNumberCopied += arr.length;                        
                    double progress = (1.0*totalNumberCopied) / (1.0*numberRows) * 100;
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
                    System.out.print("Executed batch for "+orderedTables[i]+", inserted " + arr.length + " elements");
                    System.out.println("\t Have copied a total of " + totalNumberCopied + "/" + numberRows + " rows, " + df.format(progress) + "%");
                    //Reset counter for batch size
                    counter = 0;
                }                
            }
            //Insert the last elements
            int[] arr = mysql_stmnt.executeBatch();
            System.out.println("Executed batch for "+orderedTables[i]+", inserted the last " + arr.length + " elements");
            System.out.println("------    Finished copying table " + orderedTables[i] + " ------ \n");
        }            
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBaseCopier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            javadb.close();
            mysql.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataBaseCopier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }`

}

Comment: for a bulk insert, disable keys on the mysql side. that'll speed up things somewhat. you can always re-enable/rebuild keys after the bulk copy's done.

Comment: try turning off auto commit and only commit at the end.

Comment: how about dump from your "Java DB" to a plain-text SQL file and then load that with the `mysql` command-line utility?

Comment: Marc B: Unfortunately I saw no improvement when disabling the keys. But I'm not 100% sure what you meant, I just disabled foreign key checks.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: Yes! That did it. It took 4 min 43 sec to copy everything, more than 2.3 million rows. Thank you!!

Comment: Seamus Abshere: Never got to try that solution. But noname horse's solution was fast enough and it was just a couple of lines of code.